# Using Syntaxnet with TensorFlow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, syntaxnet

I try to use Syntaxnet with TensorFlow Serving.

I found this link [here](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/master/README_api.md) . I try to run the script to launch the server:

```
# you can create a shell script with content below!

git clone https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet.git work
cd work
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
# checkout proper version of serving
cd serving
git checkout 89e9dfbea055027bc31878ee8da66b54a701a746
git submodule update --init --recursive
# checkout proper version of tf_models
cd tf_models
git checkout a4b7bb9a5dd2c021edcd3d68d326255c734d0ef0

# you need to install gRPC properly
# https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/setup
# if you have a trouble, see https://github.com/dsindex/tensorflow#tensorflow-serving

# apply patch by dmansfield to serving/tf_models/syntaxnet 
cd serving/tf_models
patch -p1 < ../../api/pr250-patch-a4b7bb9a.diff.txt
cd ../../

# configure serving/tensorflow
cd serving/tensorflow
./configure
cd ../../

# modify serving/tensorflow_serving/workspace.bzl for referencing syntaxnet
cp api/modified_workspace.bzl serving/tensorflow_serving/workspace.bzl
cat api/modified_workspace.bzl
#  ... 
#  native.local_repository(
#    name = "syntaxnet",
#    path = workspace_dir + "/tf_models/syntaxnet",
#  )
#  ...

# append build instructions to serving/tensorflow_serving/example/BUILD
cat api/append_BUILD >> serving/tensorflow_serving/example/BUILD

# copy parsey_api.cc, parsey_api.proto to example directory to build
cp api/parsey_api* serving/tensorflow_serving/example/

# build parsey_api 
cd serving
bazel --output_user_root=bazel_root build --nocheck_visibility -c opt -s //tensorflow_serving/example:parsey_api --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone --verbose_failures

# make softlink for referencing 'syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/context.pbtxt'
ln -s ./tf_models/syntaxnet/syntaxnet syntaxnet

# run parsey_api with exported model
./bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/parsey_api --port=9000 ../api/parsey_model
```

But for the line below (when building parsey_api):

```
bazel --output_user_root=bazel_root build --nocheck_visibility -c opt -s //tensorflow_serving/example:parsey_api --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone --verbose_failures
```

I got an error:

```
Extracting Bazel installation...
........
ERROR: Failed to load Skylark extension '//tensorflow/tensorflow:workspace.bzl'.
It usually happens when the repository is not defined prior to being used.
Maybe repository '' was defined later in your WORKSPACE file?
ERROR: cycles detected during target parsing.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.298s
./batch.sh: line 52: ./bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/parsey_api: No such file or directory
```

The `file workspace.bzl` is in the directory `$BUILD_DIRECTORY/tensorflow/tensorflow`

I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Bazel 0.4.4
- python gPRC installed

Thank you any suggestion is welcome.